# gulp: How do i pipe a css file in between scss files? gulp.src(['sassfile1.scss', 'cssfile.css' ,'sassfile2.scss'])

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

this is my current code part in gulpfile.js:

```
// Sass 
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', './node_modules/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/full-slider.css' ,'./sass/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

I am trying to add "full-slider.css` file in between, to minify and combine (in that order).

the content of `full-slider.css` is not added to the final `style.css`

edit:

Tried using `gulp-cssnano`: 
this way:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var fs = require('fs');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('sass', function () {

    gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', './sass/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

    gulp.src(['style.css', './node_modules/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/full-slider.css'])
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});
```

> gulp sass
>
> [16:11:45] Using gulpfile
>   /var/www/test.dev/wp-content/themes/olympos/gulpfile.js [16:11:45]
>   Starting 'sass'... [16:11:45] Finished 'sass' after 23 ms
>
> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ CssSyntaxError: /var/www/test.dev/wp-content/themes/olympos/bootstrap.scss:1:0:
>   Missed semicolon> 1 | /*!
>       |             ^   2 |  * Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 (https://getbootstrap.com)   3 |  * Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap
>   Authors

when i comment the part:

```
    gulp.src(['style.css', './node_modules/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/full-slider.css'])
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

it compiles smoothly, where is my mistake?

(theory: might this happen because of the output for the sourcemap in the generated new css file? )

Comment: Make sure the file is located at that directory

Comment: Does gulp-sass support vanilla CSS files? If not, I'd use `gulp.dest()` to copy the CSS file to a different location in your project files (can't change stuff inside node_modules), set the name to .scss (because any CSS file is valid Sass) and then run the task again with the new path.

Comment: Alternatively you could just include the file further down the task as a `concat` task, then use autoprefixer separate from the Sass task and then maybe run uglify after including all the files.

Comment: @TomOakley first solution works. can you show me a quick example of how to apply this concat fix?

Comment: add it to another task not scss task. i mean create a new task.

Comment: @RickSanchez posted as an answer. Was slightly more confusing than I originally thought, sorry.

Comment: @TomOakley i was just trying to say that coping the css file and renaming it works smoothly (your first suggestion), but the problem still exist because i'm trying to built a specific workflow with gulp ;)

Comment: @RickSanchez hey, sure stick with what works. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @TomOakley i do rather continue with the other solution you suggested since it's more practical when i add more css libraries to my project and get if raw from the npm installation (rather than playing around with files in my project) - i edited my main post with the errors and code i added to my `gulpfile.js`, can you please review?

Comment: How is bootstrap.scss being written or compiled? The error would appear to be coming from either cssnano or autoprefixer (removing these pipes one at a time would help to figure out which), which is coming across a sass file (bootstrap.scss) that has a syntax error (missing semicolon).

Answer (score 1):

Initially I thought that the best way would be to copy the CSS file to a new location in your project files (using `gulp.dest()`), set the file name to have an `.scss` extension and then run the `gulp.sass()` pipe again.

However, this isn't really using gulp-sass as it's supposed to be used (it's not a file concatenator). A better way would be to do something like this (bear in mind I haven't got time to practically test this so it may not work. Apologies.):

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', './sass/**/*.scss'])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(concat('style.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  gulp.src(['style.css', './node_modules/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/full-slider.css'])
  .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
  .pipe(cssnano())
  .pipe(concat('style.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

That probably isn't perfect, and I also realised as I was writing this that you wanted the fullslider.css file to be included after bootstrap but before your project files. Further this doesn't use sourcemaps for the second sub-task. As you can probably tell, I haven't written gulp tasks for a while! But if you have time, maybe something to play around with.

P.S `cssnano()` refers to [`gulp-cssnano`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssnano).

Comment: I installed `gulp-cssnanp` and applied it as you described (I'll edit my main post with the code) - I get an error: `gulp sass
[16:11:45] Using gulpfile /var/www/test.dev/wp-content/themes/olympos/gulpfile.js
[16:11:45] Starting 'sass'...
[16:11:45] Finished 'sass' after 23 ms

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
CssSyntaxError: /var/www/test.dev/wp-content/themes/olympos/bootstrap.scss:1:0: Missed semicolon> 1 | /*!
    |             ^
  2 |  * Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 (https://getbootstrap.com)
  3 |  * Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap Authors`