# Gulp: errors while trying to combine 2 files after compression (one is compressing sass and one css)

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I have a task named "sass" that minify .scss files and right after it does the same with .css files (and combine them together)

Tried using `gulp-cssnano`: 
this way:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var fs = require('fs');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('sass', function () {

    gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', './sass/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

    gulp.src(['style.css', './node_modules/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/full-slider.css'])
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});
```

running the task output:

> gulp sass
>
> [16:11:45] Using gulpfile
>   /var/www/test.dev/wp-content/themes/olympos/gulpfile.js [16:11:45]
>   Starting 'sass'... [16:11:45] Finished 'sass' after 23 ms
>
> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ CssSyntaxError: /var/www/test.dev/wp-content/themes/olympos/bootstrap.scss:1:0:
>   Missed semicolon> 1 | /*!
>       |             ^   2 |  * Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 (https://getbootstrap.com)   3 |  * Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap
>   Authors

when i comment the second part (responsible for minifing the regular .css files and combining them to the compresses styles.css [resulted by the sass compilation])- this part of the code:

```
    gulp.src(['style.css', './node_modules/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/full-slider.css'])
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

it compiles smoothly, where is my mistake in the second part? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you take out the bootstrap.scss from the first src, does it work fine?  Also it looks to me like you could simplify by injecting the full-slider.css file at the later point rather than another gulp.src.  Finally, you should combine and return the streams in case you will have other tasks that depend on this one.  But essentially it is complaining about an error in the bootstrap.scss file.  Can you re-install the bootstrap plugin to see if they fixed that?  And see my first question.

Comment: adding the .css file with the scss files doesn't work (see previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662606/gulp-how-do-i-pipe-a-css-file-in-between-scss-files-gulp-srcsassfile1-scss ). i removed `bootstrap.scss file` and i get the same error (which i think might be strange since there is no bootstrap here anymore), i have just installed bootstrap 2 days ago i don't think it's the problem @Mark